# Oksendal chapter 7, what does $E^x[f_1(X_{t_1})\ldots f_k(X_{t_k})]=E[f_1(X^x_{t_1})\ldots f_k(X^x_{t_k})]$ mean?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to read Oksendal's book *"Stochastic Differential Equations"*. In chapter 7, he consider processes like $$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t$$ with the usual conditions ensuring unicity. Denote by $X^x_t$ the unique solution of the above equation such that $X_0=x$. Let $Q^x$ denote the probability law of $X^x_t$ when $X_0=x$ and $E^x(\cdot)$ be the expectation with respect to $Q^x$. Now this is claimed

> [...]Hence we have $$E^x[f_1(X_{t_1})\ldots f_k(X_{t_k})]=E[f_1(X^x_{t_1})\ldots f_k(X^x_{t_k})]$$ for all Borel functions $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ and all times $t_1,\ldots,t_k$ where $E=E_P$ denotes the expectation with respect to the probability law $P=P^0$ for $\{B_t\}_{t\ge0}$ when $B_0=0$.

First I don't understand what are the processes on the left hand side : Is $X_{t_1}=X^0_{t_1}$? Or $X_{t_1}=X^x_{t_1}$? Or something else? This is not clear to me. Second, how do you show the identity properly?

Comment: I didn't see these paragraphs in Chapter 7, it might be useful to specify which page you are referring to

Comment: I think this isn't a matter of page numbers, but rather of editions of the book. That being said, I would suggest to take a look at newer versions of the book. In the fifth one for instance the statement above is used to introduce/define $Q^{x}$ and not as a proposition.

Comment: It is the 6th edition at beginning of chapter 7

Comment: Well, then likewise it might be helpful to look into an older edition ;)

Answer (score 1):

Following Øksendal's notation, the LHS means:
$$
\text{LHS}= \int_{\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)^{[0,+\infty)}}\prod_{i=1}^k f_i\left(Y_{t_i}\right) dQ^x(Y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n\cdot k}}\prod_{i=1}^k f_i\left(y_{i}\right) dQ^x_{t_1,\ldots,t_k}(y),
$$
where the second equality follows from Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem, see, for instance, Chapter 2 of Øksendal's book. The RHS means:
$$
\text{RHS}= \int_{\Omega}\prod_{i=1}^k  f_i\left(X_{t_i}^{x}(\omega)\right) dP(\omega).
$$
Then, the equality follows from a standard result called ["the law of the unconscious statistician"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) applied to the random vector $(X^x_{t_i})_{i=1}^k$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n\cdot k}$. See, for instance, Theorem 5.11 (figure below) in these [notes](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Egrigor/ptlect.pdf) of A. Grigoryan or Proposition 10.1 of Folland "Real Analysis".
[image: referenced theorem]